# Pattern matching troubles

Tags: java, regex

So I have a function that looks like this:

```
private int getNumber(String commandChunk)
    {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("R(\\d+)");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(commandChunk);
        return Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    }
```

which is getting called with "R0". I would like it to return the int: 0, but instead I am getting an illegal state exception on the return statement. What am I doing wrong? I cant see why I shouldn't be able to say `int myNum = getNumber("R0")` end up with `myNum = 0`.

Comment: For the love of FSM, make the Pattern a constant.  Why recompile it every time the method is called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`group`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) throws an `IllegalStateException` if not preceded by either [`matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) or `find`. Invoke `matches` prior to calling `group` so that the expression matches the complete `String`:

```
class NumberTest {
    final static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("R(\\d+)");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new NumberTest().getNumber("R0"));
    }

    private int getNumber(String commandChunk) {
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(commandChunk);
        if (m.matches()) {
            return Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To quote the javadoc, _"The explicit state of a matcher is initially undefined; attempting to query any part of it before a successful match will cause an IllegalStateException to be thrown. The explicit state of a matcher is recomputed by every match operation."_

Comment: What about my regex though? Why isnt it matching a group?

Comment: Because you're not calling `matches` (or `find`) so its throwing an `IllegalStateException` before the expression can match. See the demo added